# JAXB2: Mapping nested elements into the same Java class

Tags: java, jaxb, jaxb2

I'm having trouble trying to map nested elements into the same Java class.

**XML**

What I'm trying to do here is to set `id` attribute and `text` element into `SlideText` class.

```
<module name="test project">
    <slide id="1">
        <layout>
            <text>hello</text>
        </layout>
    </slide>
</module>
```

**Module class**

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Module {
    @XmlAttribute
    private String  name;

    @XmlElements({
        @XmlElement(name = "slide", type = SlideText.class)
    })
    private Slide   slide;
}
```

**Slide class**

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public abstract class Slide {
    @XmlAttribute
    private String  id;
}
```

**SlideText class**

I tried using `@XmlElementWrapper` on `text` property, but I get an exception that `@XmlElementWrapper` can only be applied to a collection.

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class SlideText extends Slide {

    // how to map this to layout/text elements?
    private String  text;
}
```

Is there a way to map `<layout><text>hello</text></layout>` into `SlideText`'s `text` property?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

To illustrate what I'm trying to accomplish here, the slide can be of any type depending on what layout is used. A `module` knows it's a `slide` but it doesn't know what slide it is, which is why I have the abstract `Slide` class.

Essentially, if this works, I'll be creating `SlideImage` and `SlideTextVideo` that extends `Slide`.

Here's how the actual XML file looks like:-

```
<module name="test project">
    <slide id="1">
        <layout-text>
            <text>hello</text>
        </layout-text>
    </slide>
</module>
<module name="test project">
    <slide id="2">
        <layout-image>
            <image-path>img.jpg</image-path>
        </layout-image>
    </slide>
</module>
<module name="test project">
    <slide id="3">
        <layout-text-video>
            <text>hello</text>
            <video-path>a.mp4</video-path>
        </layout-text-video>
    </slide>
</module>
```

Comment: Slide is a complex type. Define it as another object and place the other into this class. Does this not work for you?

Comment: @fmucar: I added more reasoning to my post above.

Comment: Side note: you don't need `@XmlRootElement` on any class other than `Module`, assuming it will always be the root element of the XML document.

Comment: Were you able to get the answer for this? Even I have something like this. I know its been long time but do you remember what you did here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use [EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) then you can leverage the @XmlPath extension for this (I'm the MOXy tech lead):

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlPath;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class SlideText extends Slide {

    @XmlPath("layout/text/text()")
    private String  text;

}
```

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/09/xpath-based-mapping-geocode-example.html

Using standard JAXB you could leverage an XmlAdapter:

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/07/xmladapter-jaxbs-secret-weapon.html

Comment: I can't get it working. I had that `@XmlPath` just like yours, but the `text` is still null.

Comment: I'm using Moxy 2.3.0-M5, if it makes any difference. :)

Comment: Okay, I fixed it. I'm missing the `jaxb.properties` file. Wow, this is awesome! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add a new class `Layout`:

```
public class SlideText extends Slide {
    @XmlElement
    private Layout layout;
}

public class Layout {
    @XmlAttribute
    private String  text;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible not to define `Layout` class at all? I'm hoping to have all the information in the concrete `Slide` classes. Thanks.

Comment: You could try making it an anonymous class within `Slide` or `SlideText`.